# Calorie Program - Java Calculation

Tags: java

the problem with this code is calculating the daily calories needed. I do not get the right amount whether it is male or female. And if I can improve in anything, I am all hears. Thanks. I am a beginner in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //variables
        int age;
        int height;
        int weight;
        String gender;
        int BMR;
        char genderChar;
        boolean male;
        String exercise;
        boolean none = false;
        boolean light = false;
        boolean moderately = false;
        boolean intensely = false;
        boolean five;
        double cal;




        //Male or Female?
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your gender? M or F: ");
        gender = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        //Determining your BMR 

        System.out.println("What is your age: ");
        age = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is your weight: ");
        weight = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is your height: ");
        height = keyboard.nextInt();

        genderChar = gender.charAt(0);

        male = genderChar == 'M';

        if (male)
        {
            BMR = (int) (66 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * age));
        }
        else
        {
            BMR = (int) (665 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age));
        }

        //Show BMR

        if (male)
        {
            System.out.println("Your BMR is " + BMR);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Your BMR is " + BMR);

        //Level of Exercises

        if (none)
        {
            cal =  (BMR * 1.2);
        }
        else if (light)
        {
            cal = (BMR * 1.375);
        }
        else if (moderately)
        {
            cal = (BMR * 1.55);
        }
        else if (intensely)
        {   
            cal = (BMR * 1.725);
        }
        else
        {
            cal = (BMR * 1.9);
        }

        System.out.println("What is your level of exercise? ");
        System.out.println("Type in none if you do not exercise. ");
        System.out.println("Type in 2 if you engage in light exercise one to three days a week.");
        System.out.println("Type in 3 if you do exercise moderately three to five times a week.");
        System.out.println("Type in 4 if you do intensely six to seven days a week.");
        System.out.println("Type in 5 if you do exercise intensely six to seven days a week and have a physically active job.");

        exercise = keyboard.nextLine();
        none = keyboard.nextLine() != null;

        System.out.println("Your daily calorie needs " + cal);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- Your code `male = genderChar == 'M';` needst o be changed to `male = genderChar.equalsIgnoreCase("M");` Since nextLine from scanner would return String and not character and to compare String you need double quotes for constant literals and to match either m or M (case in sensitive match), you need `equalsIgnoreCase` method.
- You dont need following if:

  ```
  if (male)
  {
      System.out.println("Your BMR is " + BMR);
  }
  else
      System.out.println("Your BMR is " + BMR);
  ```

Just say

```
System.out.println("Your BMR is " + BMR);
```

- Your `none`, `light` etc varaibles are never changing after you initialized them to false. So may be you want to look at them setting appropriately as per your requirement.

Comment: agreed that could be another way @jhamon

Comment: I meant that what he wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating the `cal` value before you get input from the
   user. That way, all booleans will be set to "false" which means your
   code gets to the `else` block and just calculates `cal = (BMR *
   1.9);`. Also, I think you should use switch-case in this example.

```
    System.out.println("What is your level of exercise? ");
    System.out.println("Type in none if you do not exercise. ");
    System.out.println("Type in 2 if you engage in light exercise one to three days a week.");
    System.out.println("Type in 3 if you do exercise moderately three to five times a week.");
    System.out.println("Type in 4 if you do intensely six to seven days a week.");
    System.out.println("Type in 5 if you do exercise intensely six to seven days a week and have a physically active job.");

    exercise = keyboard.nextLine();

    //Use a switch-case now
    switch(exercise) {
    case "none":
      //calculate cal here
      break; //Don't forget the break!!
    case "2":
      //calculate cal here
      break; //Don't forget the break!!
    case "3":
      //calculate cal here
      break; //Don't forget the break!!
    //continue with the rest here
    }
```

For reference, use [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)